# Django Password not encrypted, custom user model using (AbstractUser)

Tags: django-models, django-admin, field, password-hash, unordered

In Django I have replaced the user model using (AbstractUser).
Then in the admin panel area the fields are unordered. When generating a new user, the password is not encrypted, the user is saved with the password unencrypted. But then I can't access the admin panel. Returning error the username or password do not match.

In model.py

```
# from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models

# UserModel = get_user_model()

class UserAgent_mod(AbstractUser):

    phone_number = models.CharField(
        max_length=9,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )

    profile_image = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='photos_user_agent',
    )

    manage_properties = models.ManyToManyField(
        to='property_app.Property_mod',
        related_name='manage_properties',
        blank=True

    )

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.first_name} {self.last_name}'

    class Meta:
        verbose_name='User Agent'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Users Agents'
```

In admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

UserModel = get_user_model()

@admin.register(UserModel)
class UserAgentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (
        'username',
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'phone_number',
        'email',
    )

    list_filter = (
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
    )
```

in settings.py

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL= 'user_agent_app.UserAgent_mod'
```

[Demo result of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTboa.png)

Comment: I need help to order the fields and the password is encrypted. So I guess the access problem will be solved too.

Answer (score 2):

put the following code in your admin.py file:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAgent_mod as BaseUserAdmin

class UserAgentAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    fieldsets = BaseUserAdmin.fieldsets
    ADDITIONAL_USER_FIELDS = (
        (None, {'fields': ('phone_number','profile_image','manage_properties')}),
    )
    fieldsets = fieldsets + ADDITIONAL_USER_FIELDS
    list_display = (
        'username',
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'phone_number',
        'email',
    )

    list_filter = (
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
    )

admin.site.register(get_user_model, UserAgentAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0):

Whan you use `AbstarctUser` and you need to add users via the django admin panel, you should also use the `UserCreationForm` and `UserChangeForm`, so the password will be encrypted.

To do so, make a `forms.py` file in your users application and add the following code to it:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm
from .models import UserAgent_mod

class UserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

# If you want to give superuser privileges to the staff users, override the save method 
    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = self.instance
        if user.is_staff:   
            user.is_superuser = True
        return super().save(commit=True)

    class Meta:
        model = UserAgent_mod
        fields = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name') # add any other field you want


class UserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserAgent_mod
        fields = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name') # add any other field you want
```

Also add the below code to your `admin.py`:

(change the fields as you want to)

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from .forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm
from .models import UserAgent_mod


class UserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    add_form = UserCreationForm
    form = UserChangeForm
    model = UserAgent_mod
    list_display = ('email', 'is_staff', 'is_active',)
    list_filter = ('email', 'is_staff', 'is_active',)
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name')}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_staff', 'is_active')}),
    )
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('email', 'password1', 'password2', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_staff', 'is_active')}
        ),
    )
    search_fields = ('email',)
    ordering = ('email',)


admin.site.register(UserAgent_mod, UserAdmin)
```

You can read more about `AbstractUser` in [this article.](https://testdriven.io/blog/django-custom-user-model/)

Comment: Thank you for such a complete answer. This has helped me solve my problem and clarify other doubts I had.

Comment: @BasilioCristov You're welcome. I'd appreciate it if you consider an upvote and mark it as accepted answer if it helped you solve your problem.